# How to reuse the value of the target inside its assignment expression?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

How to make this work:

```
(()=>{let a={}, b; console.log((b=a[`complex and long expression`])=9*b+1}))()
```

I want to reuse the value of the target into the assignment expression.

I want to avoid writing this long:

```
(()=>{let a={}, b; console.log(a[`complex and long expression`]=9*a[`complex and long expression`]+1)})()
```

Comment: I don't want to directly access the property twice when it's using a long expression.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Please explain.

Comment: `const key = 'your long expression'; a[key] = 9 * a[key];` ?

Comment: Again, sample inputs and expected outputs would help markedly.

Answer (score 3):

Your modified question asks how to do this:

```
(()=>{let a={}, b; console.log(a[`complex and long expression`]=9*a[`complex and long expression`]+1)})()
```

without repeating yourself.

The only way to do that is to repeat the property access on `a`, but there's no reason to repeat the `complex and long expression`:

```
(()=>{let a={}, ex = `complex and long expression`; console.log(a[ex] = a[ex] * 9 + 1}))()
```

---

If it were just the `* 9`, as it was in your original question, you could have used compound assignment:

> I want to avoid writing this long:
>
> ```
> (()=>{let a={}, b; console.log(a[`complex and long expression`]=9*a[`complex and long expression`]}))()
> ```

You can use `*= 9` to do the multiplication and assignment at the same time.

```
(()=>{let a={}; console.log(a[`complex and long expression`]*=9}))()
// ---------------------------------------------------------^^
```

`*=` gets the value of the left-hand operand, multiplies it by the right-hand, and then assigns back to the left-hand operand. These *compound assignment* operators exist for most of the math and bitwise operations.

[More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Comment: I believe this is just a toy example; it would not work in general case (e.g. ``a[`...`] = a[`...`] * 9 + 1``). @Jaromanda's (now deleted) comment is probably what OP is looking for (assign the index to a variable).

Comment: @Amadan - It's oddly complex and specific for a toy example.

Comment: @Amadan - True, but there's nothing in the question suggesting a second operation after the multiplication, much less that it should be involved in assigning back to the property.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Which is exactly what I want but I can't discard this great answer.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - I'm afraid I don't understand that comment.

Comment: I want a general case - consider 1 is added to the result of the multiplication and then stored.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - Well, that's not what the question asks. Again, please update your question with the specifics of what you want. The code in the answer above does what your "long" version does. Nothing in your question talks about a second operation.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - I've added to the answer with what I *think* you want.

Comment: (@T.J.Crowder No shade implied, it was a good answer for the literal question as posed. It is an unfortunate fact that the skill to ask the question well often correlates with the skill in the subject matter; thus especially with beginners looking past the literal example is often needed. Not that I haven't done exactly the same myself... :) )

Comment: @Amadan - :-) The funny thing is, when trying to answer the *very first* version of the question, using `b` in the multiplication, the first thing I did was do the "complex and long expression" once and store the result (as above). But then the OP edited the question making the `*=` the right answer. *sigh*...